# PHP script to deploy another PHP script

Tags: php, deployment

I have a familiar system that I make for alot of people. It takes up alot of my time to manually copy the template-script I made, edit it as needed. Import the mysql databases, etc. So I was thinking to myself a few nights ago, " What if I could make a form to be filled out, where when given the correct mysql info, and correct variables such as links and style, it would go in and perform the following tasks: 1. Create a specific table in the specified mySQL database 2. Actually Create a Script that resembled the following template-code:

```
    <?php
// Creator: Will Renfroe
// All rights Reserved

//Vote Sites and MySQL
$DBNAME="DATABASENAME";
$DBUSER="DATABASENAME";
$DBPASSWORD="PASS";
$DBHOST="DATABASE HOST NAME";

///////////////////
// SCRIPT
///////////////////
mysql_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD) or die("<center>Cannot connect to MySQL</center>");
mysql_select_db($DBNAME) or die("<center>Cannot select DB</center>");
/////////

?>

<?php
    include("secure.php");
    if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)) {
    $pipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
    $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
} else {
    $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
}

if(isset($_POST['dovote'])){
check_inject();

    //Get user id from session
    $userid=secure($_POST["nick"]);
    $time=time();

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT nick,time FROM votesdb WHERE ip='$ipaddress'");
    $checkip=mysql_num_rows($query);
    $iprow=mysql_fetch_row($query);

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT time FROM votesdb WHERE nick='$userid'");
    $checkuser=mysql_num_rows($query);
    $userrow=mysql_fetch_row($query);

    if ($checkuser){
        //if user vote
        if ($checkip and $time>$iprow[1]){$canvote=1;}
        if (!$checkip and $time>$userrow[0]){$canvote=1;}
    }else{
        //if user never vote
        if ($checkip and $time>$iprow[1]){$canvote=1;}
        if (!$checkip){$canvote=1;}
    }

    //Do Vote
    if ($canvote){
        $newtime=time()+60*60*24;

        if ($checkuser){
            //update
            mysql_query("UPDATE votesdb SET time=$newtime, ip='$ipaddress', votes=votes+1, flag=flag+1 WHERE nick='$userid'");
        }else{
            //insert
            $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO votesdb(nick,time,ip,votes,flag) VALUES ('$userid',$newtime,'$ipaddress',1,1)");
        }

        //Add nick to nicklist table
        $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO nicklist(nick) VALUES ('$userid')");

        echo "<font color='green'>Thanks you for a vote. You have been rewarded 10 diamond!</font>";
    }else{
        echo "<font color='red'>You can only vote every 24 hours to get a reward.</font>";
    }
}
?>

<center>
    <form target="_blank" action="**WEBSITE URL CAN GO HERE**" method="post"> <input onclick="document.getElementById('vote2').disabled=false" value="NAME OF BUTTON" name="vote1" id="vote1" type="submit" />&nbsp;</form>
    <form method="post" action="**WEBSITE URL CAN GO HERE**" target="_blank"> <input disabled="disabled" name="vote3" value="NAME OF BUTTON" onclick="document.getElementById('vote4').disabled=false" id="vote2" type="submit" /> </form>
  </p>
  <span class="minecrafttext">Then Enter Your In-Game-Name: </span> <br />
<form method="POST">
<input name="nick" onSubmit="return nameempty();" /> <br/>
<form method="POST">
    <input name="dovote" type="submit" value="Get your diamonds!" onclick="document.getElementById('vote4').disabled=false" id="vote4" disabled="disabled"/> 
</form> 

©<a href="mailto:Willrenfroe@gmail.com">WILLRENFROE</a>
</center>

</body>
```

It needs to ask for DATABASENAME, DATABASE, USERNAME, DTABASE, PASSWORD, DATABASE HOST, links etc, can anyone help me? I tried google and couldnt  find anything.

Comment: Please do not use unquoted strings (undefined constants, php has a nasty fallback to handle them as strings which is why your code works). Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to your code and you'll know why!

Comment: Every CMS does exactly that when it installs. Just look at the install code for joomla or wordpress or any other cms you can think of and you'll see how its done. Your question is a bit givemecodez, best to try implementing the system you want and come here with specific problems you encounter. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for the types of question you should ask here.

Comment: phpbb does the same thing just to add to vascowhite's list.

Comment: don not do this : $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR); and then do something like this : $query=mysql_query("SELECT nick,time FROM votesdb WHERE ip='$ipaddress'"); make sure to escape everything before doing a mysql query. Check the ipadress against a predefined array, of accepted values. Same thing for $userid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) to store your script in a variable.

Then you can do something like [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/str_replace) to dump in the data you need. For example `str_replace('DATABASENAME, $DBNAME, $script);` to replace `DATABASENAME` in the script with the value of `$DBNAME`.